# Docker container start unlimited loop and window data full after some minutes its in run

Tags: c#, docker, while-loop, containers, crash-reports

I create a simple `hello-world` image with console application **c#** in docker but when run the container its created unlimited loop!

```cs
Hellow("n", out string result);

while (result != "y")
{
    Hellow(result, out result);
}

Environment.Exit(0);

static void Hellow(string entery, out string result)
{
    Console.Clear();
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");

    if (entery != "n")
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} is not a correct Argument", entery));
        Question(out result);
    }
    else Question(out result);
}

static void Question(out string result)
{
    Console.WriteLine();
    Console.Write("Are you want to stop container? [y/N] ");
    result = Console.ReadLine()?.ToLower()!;
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 As base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 As build
WORKDIR /src
COPY *.sln ./
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore
COPY . .

FROM build As publish
WORKDIR /src/
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

FROM base As final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/ .
CMD [ "dotnet", "dotnet-Test.dll" ]
```

Run project without docker was successful but when I run below command every thing was happened

```bash
docker run --name hellow -v temp-file:/app/temp -it hello-world
```

First create unlimited loop and **cpu** is very usage with container but I don't be careful and just close `cmd` and comeback to my work

I try to create, write and read file in `volume` folder like my education video(In video use another application for image) but `shell` doesn't let me to read and write in volume folder and suddenly docker container `stopped` and image not to see in image `section`.

I quite the docker and then I see just 3 gig free in my disk before 40 gig was free!

What is my mistake in docker usage?

And Why did this happen?

**Note :** I use linux subsystem to development in windows 10 and when I can't to read and write file i send some data in this community [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/q/1491148/1741103)